# Python GUI card program=TclError: image <image name> doesn't exist

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a GUI program to display images of a card from a file in a GUI the card is randomly selected and displayed by the clicking of a button in a gui. I have my code all finished however I am running into an error I have never seen before called a TclError: image "DECK/13c.gif" doesn't exist. 
The folder is in the same directory as the program. The file is a gif file titled DECK and the cards in the file are labeled at  so for 10 of diamonds it be DECK/10d.gif but it says it doesn't exist. Thanks in advance

```
from tkinter import *
import random

class GUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Random Images")
        self.grid()
        self._cardImage = None
        self._backOfCard = PhotoImage(file = 'DECK/b.gif')
        self._imageLabel = Label(self, image = self._backOfCard)
        self._imageLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 3)

        self._randButton = Button(self, text = "Show Random Card", 
                                  command = self._getCard())
        self._randButton.grid(row = 0, column = 1, columnspan = 2)
        if self._cardImage != None:
            self._cardImage = Label(self, image = self._getCard())
            self._cardImage.grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 3)

    def _getCard(self):
        rank = random.randint(1,13)
        suit = ['s','h','d','c']
        suit = random.choice(suit)
        strOfCard = "DECK/" + str(rank) + suit + ".gif"
        self._cardImage = strOfCard
        return self._cardImage

def main():
    GUI().mainloop()


main()
```

edit: Here is the error:

```
\__init__.py", line 2293, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))

TclError: image "DECK/11s.gif" doesn't exist
```

Comment: Check the path and name of image.  Does it exist?

Comment: @Simon already did and it does which is why I am so confused

Comment: `_getCard()` returns a filename, not an image loaded from that file - yet you are passing this value to the `image` option of a Label.  Note that you are only getting to the point where this matters accidentally, because you are actually calling the function when creating the Button, rather than specifying the name of a function to be called when the Button is clicked.